# generate a static copy of the website footer html

Tags: customization, footer, third-party-applications

Client website uses the service of a third-party content provider to maintain a TV programs page. This provider needs to have access to a file that gives the theme's footer html code.

I have managed to give him that, except that the javascript files, which should be in the footer, do not appear in the rendered html code.

Here is the complete code, sitting at /path/to/partnerfooter.php

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( '../wp-load.php' );

do_action('get_footer');
get_template_part('templates/footer');
wp_footer(); 
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts'); // no go
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you not just provide them static HTML? i.e. copy and send your rendered source code? The trouble with your current technique is it's not a _true_ WordPress request, so a lot of actions/hooks/events that are probably responsible for enqueuing your various scripts aren't fired.

Comment: You could at least try firing `wp_enqueue_scripts` _before_ the `get_template_part` call.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yup, i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( '../wp-load.php' );
// Register all scripts and styles
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');

// Execute footer hooks
do_action('get_footer');

// output the js
wp_print_footer_scripts();
wp_footer();
```

It also outputted the enqueued CSS files, so I tweaked it by making a helper function

```
function dequeue_scripts_or_styles($slug) {
    wp_dequeue_style( $slug );
    wp_deregister_style( $slug );
}
```

So the final code is

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( '../wp-load.php' );
// Register all scripts and styles
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');

// Remove things that should not sit in the footer
dequeue_scripts_or_styles( 'wc-responsive-video-scripts' );
dequeue_scripts_or_styles( 'sage/css' );


// Execute footer hooks
do_action('get_footer');

// output the js
wp_print_footer_scripts();
wp_footer();
?>
     </body>
 </html>
```